# Empty white pages in tomcat maven plugin's embedded tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

I've a Spring server application accessible from Android clients or as webapp. When I use my Android client it all works fine. But when I try to access the webapp, running it into the embedded tomcat (version 7) started with tomcat7:run from tomcat maven plugin, I get empty white pages both in `http://localhost:8080/` and in `http://localhost:8080/my-app-name`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://192.168.1.68:8080/manager</url>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>      
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.9</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you get empty page, check you application logs. If you get 404 status, then you probably deploying to another context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use version 2.0 as it's now released.
Then configure the path with

```
<path>/yourpath</path>
```

Check the logs. Is there any error message ?

Comment: I have a similar problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446836/maven-embedded-tomcat6-doesnt-start ). Where are the logs, when I run `mvn tomcat6:run` ? Directory `target\tomcat\logs` is empty.