# Maven-embedded Tomcat6 doesn't start

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-3, tomcat6

I'm trying to use embedded Tomcat6 (`mvn tomcat6:run`) to run my Vaadin application (`pom.xml` is given below).

It doesn't work - when I run it, I get the messages

```
окт 18, 2013 1:51:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
окт 18, 2013 1:51:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
окт 18, 2013 1:51:57 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9090
окт 18, 2013 1:51:57 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9090
```

And then nothing happens.

What's wrong with my project setup? How can I make Tomcat6 run my web app (as it happens with `mvn jetty:run`) ?

Here's `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Vaadin Web Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>7.1.6</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <powermock.version>1.5</powermock.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo1.maven.org</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
          Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory).

          For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added on the
          compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is no need for an
          explicit dependency.
        -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing (start) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0M8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing (end) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproduct2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproduct3</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproduct1</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.x</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
            <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
                    <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
                        way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                            <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module> 
                                </modules> -->
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- http port -->
                    <port>9090</port>
                    <!-- application path always starts with /-->
                    <path>/bookkeeping</path>
                    <useTestClasspath>false</useTestClasspath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [7.1.6,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Update 1:** I get the same problem, if I create an empty Vaadin project and try to run it using Tomcat.

1. `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST -DgroupId=your.company -DartifactId=project-name -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=war`
2. `mvn tomcat6:run`

Comment: what is output when you hit http://localhost:8080

Comment: @Satya `localhost:8080` doesn't repond.

Comment: did you try to look on thread dump? e.g. via jconsole?

Comment: The port is actually set to 9090, can you try localhost:9090 instead?

Comment: @Kojotak I tried this already.

Comment: Your run target for vaadin looks off to me, I believe they are expecting a maven target not where it's being deployed.  Try using a default maven execution that will run during a life time (ie clean, install, compile)

Answer (score 2):

tomcat6 does not provide `servlet-api:3.0`, it only 2.5 compilant container, you should use tomcat7 or write correct `web.xml`

Comment: You didn't provide it in your message.
In empty Vaading project with archetype:generate there is no web.xml at all.
You can get simple example at https://github.com/vaadin/addressbook/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml